# Azure Linked Service for a Synapse workspace

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2, linked-service

Whenever I create a `Source` in an activity in a [Synapse Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-pipelines), in the [Linked Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-linked-services) tab, I get an option to either create a new `Linked Service` or to select from the dropdown (as shown below). One selection of that dropdown includes a default Linked Service (shown below) that shows as `MySynapseWorkspaceName-WorkspaceDefaultStorage` (where MySynapseWorkspaceName is name of a [Synapse workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-create-workspace) that you create).

It seems that `MySynapseWorkspaceName-WorkspaceDefaultStorage` is the linked service that gets created when you specify an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 (`ADLSGen2`) account for your Synapse workspace.

**Question**: If a Dataset for the source or destination (Sink) of an activity in Synapse Pipeline is a `ADLSGen2` storage, can we just select the above default linked service `MySynapseWorkspaceName-WorkspaceDefaultStorage` for that dataset; or choosing this linked service (created for Synapse workspace) for other datasets may cause an issue - and hence we should avoid using this linked service for other datasets inside our Synapse workspace?

[image]

Comment: We use the default connection frequently. For ADLS work, there should be no issues.

Comment: @JoelCochran My upvote. And, can we use the same `Linked Service` in a same activity's `Source` and `Sink` datasets?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I understood that You want to know Whether same Linked Service can be used in both Source and Sink datasets ?

Unfortunately, you can not use same Linked Service in both Source and Sink.  It may cause an issue and hence you should avoid using same linked service.

Comment: This has never been my experience.

Comment: @JoelCochran You mean, from you experienced, using same linked service for the `Source` and `Sink` in same activity has worked as you expected, correct?

Comment: Yes, we use this approach frequently with no issues.